# Show a database of Firebase in a arraylist from a fragment

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, fragment, firebase-realtime-database

I call a fragment, and this has a base from Firebase for to fill a list, and I'm calling it so:

```
private void getClients() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("client");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        readClients(dataSnapshot);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}
};

private void readClients(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot dss: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Client client = dss.getValue(Client.class);
        listClients.add(client);
    }
}
```

I tried to call getClients from the createView, onStart and onResume, but don't show me the list with the data, only when I minimize this app or I change for other app, and I open again  the app, the list shows the data. How do I call or show the database, inmediately the fragment appears?

Comment: call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on listview adapter after the for loop

Comment: Thank you!!!!. That's the answer

Comment: @hello_world I see you deleted the answer you gave. But since that is the correct answer, can you post it again (or undelete it). If you add a link to for example the documentation of `notifyDataSetChanged()` and maybe even a sample snippet, it'll be perfectly acceptable and help you gain reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on listview adapter after for loop.

your adapter for the listview is set before the `listClients` populates itself, and therefore your list is empty.

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause the listview to refresh itself with the new values populated in `listClients`

```
private void readClients(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot dss: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       Client client = dss.getValue(Client.class);
       listClients.add(client);
   }
listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) out for more info